# What if my attribute name in Shopify liquid has a space? (Customer.io email system)

Tags: shopify, liquid, liquid-layout

I'm attempting to add some logic in Customer.io, which uses Shopify's Liquid markup language:

```
{% if customer.Campaigns Participated > 0 %} I also saw that you participated in a campaign, which is awesome!

If you have a second, I'd love it if you could tell me what it was that made you sign up?

{% else %}

I see you haven't had a chance to participate in your first campaign - can I ask what happened?

{% endif %}
```

The problem is that it doesn't recognize the "Campaigns Participated" property due to the space...

Is there any way I can escape this space or something?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

customer.['Campaigns Participated'] is your only hope.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, that didn't work. I guess there's no way unless we go back to removing spaces from our event names?

Comment: UPDATE: It worked! I had to remove the space between {{ and the property!!!!
THANK YOU

Comment: Welcome! Glad you made the leap.

Comment: Thank you,  `{{ attributes.["My Attribute"] }}` worked in the notifications section